# Sum and subtract operations in select query with multiple joins

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have following tables:

TABLE `ITEMS` Contains

```
ITEM_ID ITEM
-------------------
1       Food
2       Medical
3       Shopping
4       Others
```

TABLE `EXPENSE_DURATION` Contains

```
E_ID    NAME    FROM_DATE               TO_DATE
----------------------------------------------------------------
1   FEB_2012    1-Feb-2013 12:00:00 AM  28-Feb-2013 12:00:00 AM
2   MAR_2012    1-Mar-2013 12:00:00 AM  31-Mar-2013 12:00:00 AM
```

TABLE `AMOUNT_FOR_EXPENSE` Contains

```
AFE_ID  E_ID    ITEM_LIST   AMOUNT
------------------------------------
1       1       1,2,3,4     5000
2       2       1,2,3,4     6000
```

TABLE `EXPENSE` Contains

```
EXPENSE_ID  E_ID    ITEM_ID     DATE                    AMOUNT
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1          1        1           1-Feb-2013 12:00:00 AM  250
2          1        2           1-Feb-2013 12:00:00 AM  450
3          1        3           1-Feb-2013 12:00:00 AM  300
4          1        4           1-Feb-2013 12:00:00 AM  100
5          1        1           2-Feb-2013 12:00:00 AM  4500
6          1        2           2-Feb-2013 12:00:00 AM  3500
7          1        3           2-Feb-2013 12:00:00 AM  2000
8          1        4           2-Feb-2013 12:00:00 AM  1500
```

Now I want to make one stored Procedure that gives me `expense_summary`. I am passing Just `E_ID` as parameter to this stored procedure.

As a result I need one table contains respective summary.

Example: E_ID=1

Result:

```
TOTAL_OUT   TOTAL_IN    SUMMARY (IN-OUT)
12600       5000        -7600
```

I know only

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM EXPENSE WHERE E_ID=1
```

Result > 12600

And

```
SELECT AMOUNT FROM AMOUNT_FOR_EXPENSE WHERE E_ID=1
```

Result > 5000

I Know this two separate queries but I don’t know how to **merge** them and how to perform **subtraction** in **select query** with **joins**.

Please help to make select query / stored procedure so that I can generate result as I need.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following query to get the result:

```
select e.e_id, 
  e.Total_out, 
  a.amount Total_in,
  (e.Total_out - a.amount) * -1 Summary
from
(
  select sum(amount) Total_out,
    e_id
  from expense
  group by e_id
) e
left join AMOUNT_FOR_EXPENSE a
  on e.e_id = a.e_id
where e.e_id = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00140/1)

Comment: with this query i just show him how to merge them , because he asked how to merge them

Comment: @echo_me The OP request help with creating a select query that gives the result, my answer does that.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
   SELECT SUM(AMOUNT),AMOUNT FROM EXPENSE ,AMOUNT_FOR_EXPENSE  WHERE E_ID=1
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile (you can't aggregate like that without using group by), and if it did, it would attempt to cross join and it also wouldn't solve the problem even if it were syntactically correct.

Comment: @echo_me This query is not correct for various reasons, outlined by Aaron above. Please either correct it or delete it. And don't accuse others for downvoting. Upvoting and downvoting is secret - exactly so we don't have these non productive accusations. If I tell you I've upvoted your answer, will you believe me?